# biologically speaking, what would a centaur and human hybrid be like?

Tags: biology, centaur

essentially, i need to know what would happen if a centaur and a human were to have a child.
what the child would look like, what their internal anatomy would be like, etc.

currently, my idea is that the child would be a tall human with larger lungs, but something about it doesn't quite seem right so i need some more ideas.

Comment: Isn't a centaur already a human-horse hybrid?

Comment: This will depend on their genetic compatibility. So we can assume that you've assumed that as a fact. It's conceivable (no pun intended) there could be a range of different. from more or less centaur to more or less human, and all sorts inbetween.

Comment: Why can't the kid be Bottom from `A Midsummer's Night Dream`? (The human with a donkey's head.)

Comment: See https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/75966/809 and https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/27842/809 and https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/55663/809 — is there anything *else* you need?

Comment: i've already seen those posts but none of them really answered my question, which is what the child of a centaur and human would be like. they focused on the centaurs alone

Comment: Why can't the centuar be only 1/4 horse? Then it will be bipedal but have horse arms and a horse face.